# Django ManyToMany field through with extra fields does not show on both relations

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have a class `Assembly`

```
class Assembly(models.Model):

    room = models.ForeignKey("Room", related_name="assemblies")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    position = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    components = models.ManyToManyField("material.Component", through="m2m_Assembly_Components")
    connections = models.ManyToManyField("Assembly", through="Connection")
    category = models.ForeignKey("Category", default=0)
    notes = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

that has a ManyToMany Realtionship between instances of itself (`connections`).
I use an intermediary table `Connection` so that i can have additional fields for a connection between two instances of an `Assembly`.

```
class Connection(models.Model):

    source = models.ForeignKey("Assembly", related_name="source_assembly", null=True)
    destination = models.ForeignKey("Assembly", related_name="destination_assembly", null=True)
    length = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

If I have two Assemblies, lets say A and B, and I connect them by defining a new Connection with A as source and B as destination, I get B as A's connections (`A.connections.all()`), but I don't get A as B's connections.

If I don't use an intermediary table, just a `models.ManyToManyField("Assembly")` I get A as B's connections and B as A's connections.

What is my problem here?

Comment: Hmm.. without specified related_name, have you tried `assembly_set` from B's side of things?

Comment: If i not specify a related_name i get an error (don't remember exactly which it was) because i use the same ForeignKey twice.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to specify the [`through_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) argument to your `ManyToManyField`.

When Django autogenerates your through model, it knows which of the two `ForeignKey`s in it corresponds to the "local" end of the relationship, and which is the "remote" end. However, when you specify a custom intermediary model, this makes it more difficult. It is possible that Django just takes the first `ForeignKey` in the intermediary model pointing to the right target model, which in both cases happens to be `source` here (although I'm not sure this is really the case, and if it is, it might be a bug).

Try to see if using `through_fields=('source', 'destination')` helps.

Comment: I just tried the `through_fields` but it does not help.

Comment: @Bouni I explained in my answer why you won't get symmetrical connections between A and B. However, you must use `through_fields` for properly defining what is source and what is destination.

Comment: @AKS has a good point in [the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35647525/687488) – when you use a custom `through` model, the relationship is automatically no longer symmetrical, which means every side of the relationship will see a different set of objects. Symmetry is implemented by using two rows in the intermediary table for every pair of related objects, so you'll have to do this yourself if you want to use your custom through model. That also means any extra data will be stored in the database twice.

Comment: @koniiiik Very good point about adding two rows in the database but it does come with extra management and care. :)

Comment: I think i will go the easy way and use the default Django ManyToMany field and go without the extra fields. Anyway thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the @koniiiik's answer regarding [`through_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields):

> Recursive relationships using an intermediary model are always defined as non-symmetrical – that is, with `symmetrical=False` – therefore, there is the concept of a `“source”` and a `“target”`. In that case `'field1'` will be treated as the `“source”` of the relationship and `'field2'` as the `“target”`.

and, in your case it is `source` and `destination`.

Since you are using an intermediary model `Connection`, the relationship is not symmetrical anymore. Therefore, `A.connections.all()` and `B.connections.all()` will return different results.

```
A.connections.all() #all assemblies where A is source
B.connections.all() # all assemblies where B is source
```

if you add a connection:

```
Connection(source=A, destination=B)
```

you can find all the assemblies where B is destination using:

```
B.destination_assembly.all().values_list('source', flat=True) # this will include A
```

Comment: The suggestion `...values_list('source_assembly', flat=True)` gives me no results at all.

Comment: Did you update the declaration with `through_fields` e.g. `models.ManyToManyField("Assembly", through="Connection", through_fields=('source', 'destination'))`

Comment: Yes, i've added the through_fields a couple of minutues before i tried your suggestion because of @koniiik 's suggestion

Comment: If possible; please delete existing entries, migrate, add a new connection and see if you get any results with `B.destination_assembly.all()`?

Comment: Ok, I will try that as a last test :-)

Comment: Tried that, too. But same result.