# multiple foreign keys in intermediate table of same table DJANGO

Tags: django-models

In many to many relationships with the intermediate table, I use multiple foreign keys. but got error like
*The model is used as an intermediate model by 'examples.Employee.designation', but it has more than one foreign key from 'Employee', which is ambiguous. You must specify which foreign key Django should use via the through_fields keyword argument*
my models are with intermediate table

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    designation =models.ManyToManyField(Designation,related_name='+',through = 'HRManagement',blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    join_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    leave_date = models.DateField(blank = True, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    password = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
    address = models.TextField()

class Designation(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)

class HRManagement(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name = 'employee', null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    designation = models.ForeignKey(Designation, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None,null=True)
    reportto = models.ForeignKey(Employee, null=True, related_name='reportto',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

how could I fix this error? please help me in models building

Answer (score 3):

The through model (`HRManagement`) contains two `ForeignKey`s to the same model (`Employee` being linked to by both `employee` and `reportto`), which is ambiguous. This is what [`through_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) is for.

Try adding `through_fields=('employee', 'designation')` to `designation` so that the field is declared as:

```
designation = models.ManyToManyField(Designation, related_name='+', through='HRManagement', blank=True, through_fields=('employee', 'designation'))
```

[As a different answer in a different question points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35647525), the order of the fields in `through_fields` is `(source, destination)`. If swapped, `makemigrations` errors out with [E339](https://github.com/django/django/commit/aaad3e27ac7cfcbbfeac6353d17d27e8da523cc8#diff-3010fc5a498b7171c342520f34507968R2075).